# Pandas multi-index lookup

Tags: python, pandas

How would I create a new column with aggregated values using a multi-index?

For example in the following DataFrame, how would I create a new column with an aggregated list of products based off of an index of region, market?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'product' : ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Omega', 'Omega', 'Delta', 'Delta'],
               'region' : [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1],
               'market' : ['small', 'large', 'small', 'small', 'large', 'small', 'small', 'medium']})
```

Looking to go from:

```
    +---------+--------+--------+
    | product | region | market |
    +---------+--------+--------+
    | Alpha   |      1 | small  |
    | Alpha   |      2 | large  |
    | Beta    |      1 | small  |
    | Beta    |      1 | small  |
    | Omega   |      3 | large  |
    | Omega   |      1 | small  |
    | Delta   |      2 | small  |
    | Delta   |      1 | medium |
    +---------+--------+--------+
```

To:

```
    +---------+--------+--------+----------------------------+
    | product | region | market |          product_list      |
    +---------+--------+--------+----------------------------+
    | Alpha   |      1 | small  | ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Omega'] |
    | Alpha   |      2 | large  | ['Alpha']                  |
    | Beta    |      1 | small  | ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Omega'] |
    | Beta    |      1 | small  | ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Omega'] |
    | Omega   |      3 | large  | ['Omega']                  |
    | Omega   |      1 | small  | ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Omega'] |
    | Delta   |      2 | small  | ['Delta']                  |
    | Delta   |      1 | medium | ['Delta']                  |
    +---------+--------+--------+----------------------------+
```

Duplicates dropped (e.g. Beta, 1, small isn't duplicated in the product_list ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Omega']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), where duplicities are removed by converting to `set` and then use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for convert to `list`:

```
df['product_list'] = df.groupby(['region','market']).transform(lambda x:
                                                                set(x.tolist()))
df['product_list'] = df['product_list'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
print df

   market product  region          product_list
0   small   Alpha       1  [Alpha, Beta, Omega]
1   large   Alpha       2               [Alpha]
2   small    Beta       1  [Alpha, Beta, Omega]
3   small    Beta       1  [Alpha, Beta, Omega]
4   large   Omega       3               [Omega]
5   small   Omega       1  [Alpha, Beta, Omega]
6   small   Delta       2               [Delta]
7  medium   Delta       1               [Delta]
```